# Answer draft deleted without warning when signing up

Tags: bug, draft

I recently saw a question I wanted to answer, so I typed out an answer in the answer box. After I finished writing it, I realized I couldn't post it because I hadn't created an account on that stack yet. I clicked the button to create an account on that stack and got no warning about navigating away from the page. When I returned to the question I found about 2/3 of my answer text was deleted from the text box.

Usually, I get a warning when navigating away from a page with an unposted answer, so I assumed here when I got no such warning that my answer would be saved for me. So it seems like something is not working right in this instance. Either I should have gotten a warning when clicking to create an account, or else my answer should have been properly saved as a draft before I left the page.

I'm running Chrome (version 79.0.3945.130) on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, there is a warning (even when the complete post is saved as a draft), so the fact that it didn't trigger for you is a bug. It would be nice to know your browser and OS versions, so we can tell whether the bug is in your browser or within SE.

Comment: I'm running Chrome (version 79.0.3945.130) on Windows 10. I get the warning when I click most links, but not the 'Sign up using Email and Password' button below the answer box and this happens consistently.